# Error when trying to get the value of an input number with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to simulate a shopping cart with just Javascript, but I'm getting an error everytime I update the value of the input number to update the table: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

When I use console.log to see the value, it shows the value so I don't know why it says it cannot read the property value.

I have no idea what's wrong. Here is my function to add the items to the table:

```
    function addRowsToTable(product_value, product_name, product_image, product_price, product_qty, sub_total){
    //console.log(value);
    if (sessionStorage.Total_Items > 0){
        var table = document.getElementById("shop-table");
        var row = table.insertRow(1);
        row.innerHTML = "<tr>\n" +
            "                <td>\n" +
            "                    <button value=\"" + product_value + "\" onclick=\"deleteRowFromTable(this);\">Remove</button>\n" +
            "                </td>\n" +
            "                <td>\n" +
            "                    <img src=\""+ product_image+"\" style=\"width: 60px; height: 80px;\">\n" +
            "                </td>\n" +
            "                <td>" + product_name + "</td>\n" +
            "                <td>\n" +
            "                    <input id=\"" + product_value + "\" type=\"number\" name=\"quantity\" min=\"0\" max=\"20\" value=\""+ product_qty +"\" onclick=\"updateFromShoppingCart(this);\">\n" +
            "                </td>\n" +
            "                <td>"+ product_price +"</td>\n" +
            "                <td>"+ sub_total+"</td>\n" +
            "            </tr>";
    }
}
```

Here is my function to update the table from after I change the value of input number tag by using the onchange event:

```
    function updateFromShoppingCart(element){
    saveItemsQtyToStorage();
    loadItemsQtyFromStorage();

    console.log(element.value);
    if(element.value > 0){
        var table = document.getElementById("shop-table");
        var new_quatity = element.value;
        var id = element.id;
        ItemsQty[id] = new_quatity;
        var parentRowIndex = element.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        //console.log(ItemsQty[id]);
        table.rows[parentRowIndex].cells[5].innerText = ItemsQty[id] * ItemPrice[id];
        saveItemsQtyToStorage();
        loadItemsQtyFromStorage();
        updateFromShoppingCart();
        cartTotalPrice();
    }
    else{
        deleteRowFromTable(ele);
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML Code of the Table"

```
<table id="shop-table">
            <tr>
                <th>Remove Product</th>
                <th>Product Image</th>
                <th>Product Description</th>
                <th>Qty.</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Picture of the error:
[image: Error]

Thanks.

Comment: You call `updateFromShoppingCart();` without any parameter, so when it comes to print that console statement it will be undefined.

Comment: I'm using "this" when calling the function. So I don't understand why

Comment: In which case is it scoped properly?

Comment: Why are you calling it recursively anyway?

Comment: If I increase the value of the input number, I get the error at the end of console.log(element.value); but it shows the right value.

Comment: I must have called it recursively by accident; I will fix that.

Comment: Let us know if removing that line fixes your problem

Comment: user184994 you were right, It was that recursive call causing the error. Now it runs fine. Can you post as an answer so I can mark it as a solution? Thanks man!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're recursively calling `updateFromShoppingCart();` without passing the `element` parameter, so when it executes, `element` is undefined, and you will get that error on the `console.log` line.

If you remove the recursive call, it should work.